# Поиск координат точки

Tags: математика, алгоритм, c++

Как узнать координаты точки, которая движется по замкнутому пути. В качестве параметров указывается скорость и время движения, количество "кругов" которые точка может пройти не ограничено.

[тут была зарисовка пути, но ссылка устарела]

Comment: А начальная точка движения случайно не указана?

Comment: Если скорость постоянная, то можно для этой штуковины написать параметрическое уравнение `(x, y) = f(x0, y0, t, V),` определяющее положение точки на полилинии в любой момент времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вычисляете длинну пройденого пути по скорости и времени, потом например последовательно складываете длину отрезков пока она меньше пройденного пути. Так мы найдём искомый отрезок на котором точка. Зная остаток пути на этом отрезке и координаты начала и конца, думаю как найти координаты точки в данном случае догадаетесь из школьного курса геометрии?

Comment: Да, дальше сам все найду. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Что значит "складываете длину отрезков"? Я так поняла, что задача решается на плоскости, так что сложение должно быть векторным: не длины, а координаты!

Comment: @neofit, а что за зверь такой - "векторное сложение координат" ? Скорость, движение по пути. А не вектор скорости. Т.е. направляющий вектор скорости задаётся самим путём.

Comment: Координаты складывать не надо, надо прибавлять к координатам сдвиг, порожденный скоростью. Если задано, например, что начальные координаты (2, 3), а скорость равна 5 - куда попадет точка? Это зависит от направления скорости. Например, в направлении (-1, 3) за единицу времени точка сдвинется на вектор $%-{5\over\sqrt 10}, {15\sqrt 10}$%. Т.е. попадет в точку $%2-{5\over\sqrt 10}, 3+{15\sqrt 10}$%.  

Здесь что, формулы не пишутся? over - дробь, sqrt - корень

Comment: Чтож вы постоянно смешиваете скорость то как вектор то как число?
Если скорость равна 5 - то это значит у нас одномерный случай, а если скорость равна (-1,3) = это уже двухмерный. В данном случае задачу можно свести к одномерному случаю для нахождения позиции на отрезке, а усложнять двухмерным вектором смысла нет вообще никакого.

Comment: Да, согласна. Просто меня ввело в заблуждение слово "кривая", которую свести к одномерному случаю труднее. 

Думаю, все дело в определенных привычках. Я больше сижу на "Математике", там у нас не принято картинки и др. давать в виде ссылки, все вставляется непосредственно в вопрос (модераторы за этим следят). В таком случае я бы заметила, что случай линейный.

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что приходит в голову:

1. Находим длины отрезков и суммируем. Получаем общую длину пути.
2. Из 1 можно найти на каком из отрезков находится точка в данный момент и "расстояние" до последней пройденной точки.
3. Так как две точки мы знаем, третья - между ними, которую будет легко найти, что-то вроде:

> АВ^2 = (Аx-Вх)^2+(Ау-Ву)^2
>
> AM = L (известная нам длина)
>
> Mx = Ax + (Bx-Ax)*AM/AB
>
> My = Ay + (By-Ay)*AM/AB